# trigger to check avg salary of the department before inserting new record

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, mutation

lets say employee table is as below

```
 EID    ENAME   DEPTNO  SALARY
 1      john    10      100
 2      jau     10      300
 3      cau     10      200
 4      cha     20      200
 5      cwea    20      500
 6      dan     20      200
 7      an      20      300
```

I have to check if any new employee is added, the new employee salary should be greater than the average salary in that department, and this should be done in triggers.

so I have created trigger as below

```
create or replace trigger tg_emp  before insert on employee for each row  
declare 
avgsal number; 
highsalary EXCEPTION; 
BEGIN   
select avg(salary) into avgsal from employee where deptno = :NEW.deptno; 
if :NEW.salary < avgsal 
then   
raise highsalary; 
end if; 
EXCEPTION 
when highsalary then
Raise_Application_Error (-20343, 'salary is less than the avg salary in this 
department');  
WHEN others THEN  
Raise_Application_Error (-20353, 'other error probably table mutation 
error');  
END;
```

as you know with this code it works for only individual inserts like below

```
insert into employee values (8, 'jj', 10, 500);
```

but if it is a multiple inserts at once like

```
insert into employee
select seq_emp.next, 'ffgg', 10, 400 from all_tab_columns where rownum < 5;
```

it throws table mutation error(I know the above insert does not make sense but I am using it as just an example for multi insert in one statement).

so how can we resolve this using global temporary tables?

I think I was able to solve it using 1 GTT and 1 before statement trigger and 1 before row trigger as below

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE employee_GTT (
id           NUMBER,
name  VARCHAR2(20),
deptno number,
salary number
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

statement level before trigger

```
create or replace trigger emp_avg_load  before insert on employee 
begin
insert into dept_avg
select deptno, avg(salary), count(deptno) from employee group by deptno;
dbms_output.put_line('getting data from GTT');
end;
```

row level before trigger

```
create or replace trigger tg_emp  before insert on employee for each row  
declare 
avgsal number;
ct number;
highsalary EXCEPTION; 
BEGIN  
avgsal := :new.salary; 
select avgsal, count into avgsal, ct from dept_avg where deptno = 
:NEW.deptno;
if :NEW.salary < avgsal 
then   
raise highsalary; 
else
update dept_avg
set count = count +1,
avgsal = (avgsal+:NEW.salary)/(count+1)
where deptno = :NEW.deptno;
 end if; 
EXCEPTION 
when highsalary then
Raise_Application_Error (-20343, 'salary is less than the avg salary in this 
department');  
WHEN others THEN  
Raise_Application_Error (-21343, 'some other error'); 
END;
```

Please correct me if I get it wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that executing the single line insert it works? You can't make a query on the same table you're using the trigger. You'd have to use Compound triggers. Regardless of that case, in order for you not having that many triggers on the same table, I would recommend you create a Compound trigger. A quick google will help you on the sintax. But if you need help, just shout.

Comment: yes, executing a single line insert will work, this is an exception for mutating table error. I will look for compound trigger. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use the temporary table is good idea at first.

But the way you update the average salary ***during the transaction*** looks ***wrong*** to me. Indeed, depending on how Oracle handles the update (order of inserts), you won't have the same results.

- First, since you only insert employee when salary is above average, then average can only increase.
- Now , if highest salary is inserted first, then average might increase too much for the next employee to be inserted.

You are having difficulties because your requirement isn't clear enough.

I do not think it is real use case to change the average salary while you are inserting the rows. You must think of it at a transaction level: thus, average salary is defined **before** transaction happens. So no need to have the average change while you are inserting. Just let the average stay the same during transaction.

---

**I would remove this part:**

```
else
  update dept_avg
     set count = count +1
       , avgsal = (avgsal+:NEW.salary)/(count+1)
  where deptno = :NEW.deptno;
```

Comment: Actually GTT has to be updated because, in a single insert statement, I can have multiple inserts into the same department below is an example.



    insert into employee
    select 8, 'jj', 10, 600 from dual 
    union 
    select 9, 'jgh', 10, 250 from dual








before these inserts Avg for dept 10 is 200, first insert satisfy the avgsal condition, but now if I am not updating the GTT then the second insert also satisfies the condition, how ever if the GTT is updated with the first insert then avgsal for dept 10 will be 300 so second insert will fail.

Comment: I just wouldn't use a trigger to do what you intend. Overcomplicated. And requirement seems not logical. You could handle this easier with a PL SQL package.